# How to put Two Drawable in Spinner on left side in android

Tags: android, spinner, android-drawable

*How can i Put Two Drawables in the left side of Spinner in android?*

I have a Row in which one is an *ImageView* and the other is a *TextView* and Spinner in the last. Whenever I touch on the row spinner, it should be open.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create custom spinner please find example [here](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107)

Comment: i just to open spinner on the whole click of row

Comment: Then create a expandable list view with custom cell layout. hope this will work.